# slick slider not working after dynamic change

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

this is my code when i everything working ok, until i try to do ajax call this is the case i change the number of images from another website, after ajax call its stop autoplay the picture someone know how to do this?
things i try:
1. i try to initialize after the change and the slider still stop.
2. i try to add class with width to slider .
3. i try initialize without function.
the main things i try to accomplish is to check if someone change the picture if there is better way to do this i will be glad to see.

```
 <?php
    /*take time form file becuse dont wont to use db*/
  $my_file = 'file.txt';
  $handle = fopen($my_file, 'r+') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file);
  $data = fread($handle,filesize($my_file));
  $data =$data.'000';
  ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>website slider</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./slick/slick-theme.css">
    <style>
    img {
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    .imgc{
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- silc that i take from upload folder -->
    <div class="your-class " id="exampleImage" >
      <?php
      $images = glob("upload/*.*");
      foreach($images as $image)
      {
        echo '<div><img class="i" src="./'.$image.'" ></div>';
      }
      ?>
    </div>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="./slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      function sliderInit(){
        $('.your-class').not('.slick-initialized').slick({
          slidesToShow: 1,
          infinite: true,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          autoplay: true,
          pauseOnHover:true,
          autoplaySpeed: <?php echo trim($data); ?>
        });

      };
      /*function for full size*/
      function toggleFullscreen(elem) {
        elem = elem || document.documentElement;
        if (!document.fullscreenElement && !document.mozFullScreenElement &&
          !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement) {

            /*$('.your-class').slick('slickPlay');*/
            sliderInit();

            if (elem.requestFullscreen) {
              elem.requestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
              elem.msRequestFullscreen();
            } else if (elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
              elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
            } else if (elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
              elem.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
            }

          } else {
            sliderInit();
            /* $('.your-class').slick('slickPlay');*/
            if (document.exitFullscreen) {
              document.exitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
              document.msExitFullscreen();
            } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
              document.mozCancelFullScreen();
            } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
              document.webkitExitFullscreen();
            }
          }
        }
        /*call function full size when click on img*/   
        document.getElementById('exampleImage').addEventListener('click', function() {
          toggleFullscreen();
        });

        /*check if there is any change on img myabe add more or delete*/
        setInterval(adddata, 20*1000);
        function adddata(){

          $.ajax({
            url :"adddata.php",
            success:function(data){
              $('#exampleImage').html(data);


              setInterval(sliderInit, 1000);
              $('.your-class').slick('slickPlay');
            }
          })
        }

      });
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to `.slick("unslick")` then add your content or use `.slick("slickRemove")` to remove all the slides you want to replace, and then `.slick("slickAdd")` to add the new ones.